# Changing the value in a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have a sheet where I want to change the value in a range of cells in a different column than my selection. I use VBA because it's part of a code that sends information to a certain printer. I would like to let the macro also show that the selection has been printed.

**To clarify:**
- When I select F4:F10, I want the cells G4:G10 changed to a text value "Yes".
- When I select F4:F15, I want the cells G4:G15 changed to a text value "Yes".

I've searched the forums and I found/made the following:

```
Sheets("INPUT").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "Yes"
```

That works perfectly fine, however it only changes the value of one cell and not a range of cells.

Is there a way to change a range of cells to "Yes" instead of just one cell?

Comment: Adding to @QHarr's answer, you need to understand the difference between `ActiveCell` and `Selection`. In your code you use `ActiveCell`, which is *always* one cell while `Selection` can be several cells - and even non-adjacent cells (in this case you need to use `Areas` property). Indeed, `Selection` can be anything - cells, shapes, charts (well, charts *are* shapes :) ) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Selection.Offset(0,1).Value = "Yes"
```

This is where `Selection` is your range selected. This is offset by 1 column and has value of `"Yes"` assigned in one go.

Comment: I kinda missed giving the whole event part though.

Comment: `Selection.Offset(,1).Value = "Yes"` is shorter :)

Comment: That it is indeed :-)

Comment: @JohnyL this is a slippery slope... soon we'll be counting bytes like over at [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com) :-)

Comment: If only we could compete at code golf but I can’t imagine vba ever winning

Comment: @QHarr If the selection is 1 column, then the following is possible too: `Selection.Columns(2).Value = "Yes"` :) Although code didn't get any shorter :(

Comment: We can drop .Value and use default member Selection.Columns(2) = "Yes"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's my shot at this problem. I'm not quite sure what triggers your current code so I thought it made sense to catch it via the [Worksheet.SelectionChange Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange).

This will update the value of all `G4:G10` *only* if you've selected all of `F4:F10` and likewise will only change `G4:G15` if you select all of `F4:F15`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim intersectedAll As Boolean
    Dim cell As Range


    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = Range("F4:F10")

    If Target.count = rng1.count Then
        intersectedAll = True

        For Each cell In rng1
            If Intersect(Target, rng1) Is Nothing Then
                intersectedAll = False
            End If
        Next cell

        If intersectedAll = True Then
            Target.offset(0, 1).value = "Yes"
            intersectedAll = False
        End If
    End If


    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng2 = Range("F4:F15")

    If Target.count = rng2.count Then
        intersectedAll = True

        For Each cell In rng2
            If Intersect(Target, rng2) Is Nothing Then
                intersectedAll = False
            End If
        Next cell

        If intersectedAll = True Then
            Target.offset(0, 1).value = "Yes"
            intersectedAll = False
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, try to avoid using Selection where possible.  Here's an alternate that prompts the user to select the range, and then updates the corresponding cells in the column to the right:

```
Sub tgr()

    Const sUpdatedValue As String = "Yes"

    Dim rSelected As Range
    Dim rArea As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rSelected = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select Range of Cells." & Chr(10) & _
                                                 "Note that the cells in the column to the RIGHT of the selection will be updated.", _
                                         Title:="Range Selection", _
                                         Default:=Selection.Address, _
                                         Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rSelected Is Nothing Then Exit Sub   'Pressed cancel

    For Each rArea In rSelected.Areas
        rArea.Offset(, 1).Value = sUpdatedValue
    Next rArea

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working perfectly thanks to the above replies. Much appreciated!

I'm not sure how to close this thread or if that's nescessary, but "Case closed"